# How to get CIE Lab values from an icc profile?

Tags: objective-c, colors, color-profile, color-management

If I have cmyk values and a cmyk icc profile.
Can I obtain CIE Lab values for an icc profile.

I try to use little CMS, but I always get incorrect Lab values.

```
cmsHPROFILE profile = cmsOpenProfileFromFile("SWOP2013C5.icc", "r");
cmsHTRANSFORM xform = cmsCreateTransform(profile, TYPE_CMYK_FLT, 
                                         NULL, TYPE_Lab_FLT, INTENT_PERCEPTUAL, 0);

float cmykValues[] = {100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0,0};
float labValues[3];
cmsDoTransform(xform, cmykValues, labValues, 1);
```

Thanks

Comment: I get L=61.886, a=-40.6187 b=-47.7315.  What were you expecting?

Comment: I get the same values. I just wonder: Shouldn't the third argument to `cmsCreateTransform()` be a handle to a Lab profile, as created by `cmsCreateLab4Profile()` or `cmsCreateLab2Profile()` ?

Comment: Hi Dietrich, Thanks
Same with my values. but I use http://colormine.org/color-converter calculator deal with SWOP2013C5.icc, I get different values.
So I confuse.

Comment: @CocoaUser: What values do you get with that color converter?

Comment: L:65.46164983037454
A:-14.201067914263454
B:-41.69048623352929